# Django with multiple databses Mongodb and Neo4j

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb, neo4j, neomodel

I am using **Mongo** as my primary database and **Neo4j** to store some relations.Hope Neo4j can reduce the query time for complicated searches in my application.I am confused regarding how to maintain relations between the two.

Here my question **how can we create relationship between tables from two different databases** in this case?

I am working on **Python3.6, Django2.1**, django-neomodel 0.0.4,and Djongo 1.2.30

Here is my models.py sample:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
''' Listing Model for mongo database '''
create_time = models.DateTimeField()
category = models.EmbeddedModelField(
    model_container=Category,
)
subcategory = models.EmbeddedModelField(
    model_container=Subcategory,
    model_form_class=SubcategoryForm
)
...


class Listingnode(DjangoNode):
    uid = UniqueIdProperty()
    list_id = StringProperty()
    status = StringProperty()
    created = DateTimeProperty(default=datetime.utcnow)
    price_range = RelationshipTo('PricerangeNodes','PRICE_RANGE')
    tags = RelationshipTo('TagNodes','TAGS')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an auto generated property `id` to the MongoDB entity as well as to the Neo4j entity, store the `id` in the to be linked respectively other entity and load the object via an object graph mapping library (neo4j-ogm) by the stored `id` if necessary.

## 1. MongoDB part (Java version)

### 1.1 YourMongoEntity

```
@Document
public class YourMongoEntity {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @Indexed(unique = true)
  private String furtherIdentifier;

  // For reasons of clarity the default constructor, getter and setter are omitted.  
}
```

### 1.2 YourMongoEntityDAO

```
@Repository
public interface YourMongoEntityDAO extends MongoRepository<YourMongoEntity, String> {
  YourMongoEntity findById(String id);
}
```

## 2. Neo4j part (Java version)

### 2.1 YourNeo4jEntity

```
@NodeEntity
public class YourNeo4jEntity  {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Index(unique = true)
  private Long furtherIdentifier;

  // For reasons of clarity the default constructor, getter and setter are omitted.  
}
```

### 2.2 YourNeo4jEntityDAO

```
@Repository
public interface YourNeo4jEntityDAO extends Neo4jRepository<YourNeo4jEntity, Long> {
  YourNeo4jEntity findId(Long id);
}
```